# Is there a way to use rxjs with ng2-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, ng2-charts

I cant find a way to implement a live charts with ng2-charts.

I get an error when I do :

```
<div *ngIf="(lineChartData$ | async)!=null">
    ....
    <canvas baseChart width="100" height="200"
      [datasets]="lineChartData$ | async" <<-ERROR: "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"
       ....
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I think that even if I would make it work some how, it would be the worst way to do it.

---

Please recommend on any other liberies that has a build-in live charts if there is no solution to this error.

---

**EDIT:**

**app.component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="(lineChartData$ | async)!=null">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div style="display: block;">
        <canvas baseChart width="100" height="200"
                [datasets]="lineChartData$ | async"   <<<-- ERROR
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [colors]="lineChartColors"
                [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
        <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of lineChartData">
          <td *ngFor="let label of lineChartLabels; let j=index"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {AppState} from "../../redux/design/app-state";
import {AngularFire, AuthProviders, FirebaseObjectObservable} from "angularfire2";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';
import {AuthActions} from "../../redux/actions/auth.actions";
import {UserService} from "../../services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
  private lineChartData$:Observable<Array<any>>;
  constructor(private authActions: AuthActions,
              private af: AngularFire,
              private userService:UserService,
              private store:Store<AppState>){}
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lineChartData$=Observable.interval(500)
      .map(index=>[{data: [65, 59, index, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
          {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
          {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}
        ]);
  }
// lineChart
  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // dark grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,1)'
    },
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';


  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `lineChartData$`?

Comment: Hi @Martin , I added the class code. Thanks

Comment: Add `[data]="{}"` to your canvas  and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about `ng2-charts` but the error suggests the problem is somewhere else.

The doc on `ngOnInit` says:

> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.

So this lifecycle event is called after the view is initialized. Your `lineChartData$` is defined as:

```
private lineChartData$:Observable<Array<any>>;
```

... and it's not initialized until `ngOnInit()` call. So the view tries to bind `lineChartData$` which is still `undefined` at that time. Thus the error message thrown probably from `ng2-charts` internals.

Comment: Okay I moved the initializtion to the constractor and its working good. But I thougth `<div *ngIf="(lineChartData$ | async)!=null">` should not create anything until lineChartData got something at the first time. + the rendering  looks very bad. Is there a way to make it any better?

Comment: I don't know what `async` pipe does when chained with `undefined`. Maybe it returns `undefined` which isn't equal to `null`. I don't know how your rendering looks.